# QNetworkAccessManager finished signal is not emitted when compiled in release mode (VS 2005)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a class that reads web pages. It works as expected when it is built in the debug mode in Visual studio, but doesn't work when it is built in release mode.

Basically, the `QNetworkAccessManager`'s finished signal never gets emitted.

I have the code stripped to the bare working minimum and it still doesn't work. I have tried to use `QtNetworkd4.lib` in release mode (the same library as in debug mode) and disable optimization, but no effect.

Qt version 4.4

***Edit***
Here is some sample code.

**Header:**

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QStringList>

class WebReader : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QStringList *pageData_;
    WebReader();
    ~WebReader();
    void fetch(const QString &url);

public slots:
    void slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);

protected:
    QNetworkAccessManager *netManager_;

private: 
    QNetworkReply *netReply_;
};
```

**Cpp:**

```
WebReader::WebReader(){
    netManager_ = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    pageData_ = NULL;
    connect(netManager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), 
                            this, SLOT(slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
}
WebReader::~WebReader(){    
}

// Send a request to read a web page
void WebReader::fetch(const QString &url){
    netReply_ = netManager_->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
}

// SLOT that accepts the read data from the webpage
void WebReader::slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    if (NULL != pageData_){
        delete pageData_;
    }
    pageData_ = new QStringList(QString(reply->readAll()).split(QString("\n")));
    netReply_->deleteLater();
}
```

As you see, it is stripped down to a bare minimum that works in debug mode.

Comment: Works for me both in release and debug mode when compiled from Qt Creator using Visual C++ Express 2010 compiler.

Comment: Why do you use old version of Qt (current is 4.7.1) and old version of Visual C++ (current is 2010)?

Comment: @ravil, you should check official Qt bug tracker http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com before asking questions like this.

For example, there is unresolved bug like you posted: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-5997.

Comment: @Johnny Why do you think QTBUG-5997 is related to this question?

Comment: @Piotr, this question generally relates to one of the similar Qt bugs. Currently there are several active bugs with QNAM and finished() signal.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost
I will try to poke around and see if I can pinpoint some of the project settings that cause this problem. Other signals (i.e. QTimer's timeout) get emitted correctly when compiled in release mode.  
I am using VS 2005 because that's what I have the license for. We have other components that were built using Qt 4.4, so we haven't migrated to the new version yet, because everything is stable.

Comment: @Johnny  
Thanks for the advice, I am still new to Qt. I did, however, search Google before asking, but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Copy **libeay32** and **ssleay32** to the same folder with your program.